# Elegant Way of getting User Height Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, user-input

I was developing an android application where I needed to ask for user input specifically their height. Was there an elegant way of getting the user height without having 2 textboxes (1 for ft. and the other for inches)? I was hoping for maybe some type of scroller that can scroll through different heights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Alert Dialog with two [Number Pickers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker). Here is a sample example of Months picker

XML will be like this

```
 <NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/pickerMonth"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Picker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp" />
```

and you can set values in the picker in the following way

```
 binding.pickerMonth.run {
  minValue = 0
  maxValue = 11
  value = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
  displayedValues = arrayOf(
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July",
    "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
  )
}
```